# Solving double integrals: iterated integration vs. polar coordinates

Tags: lebesgue-integral, polar-coordinates

I have to solve the following integral

$$
\int_\Omega \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} dxdy, \;\; \Omega = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: 1<x^2+y^2<4,x>0,y>0 \}.
$$

I rewrited the domain to be simple with respect to the $x$-axis:

$$
\Omega^{'} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: 1<x<2, \sqrt{1-x^2} < y < \sqrt{4-x^2} \}.
$$

Solving now the integral

$$
\int_{1}^{2} \left( \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dy\right)dx,
$$

the result is $\;\frac{3}{4}\mathrm{ln(4)}\;$, which is approximately $1.039$. This is also the result of the integral when solving it with WolframAlpha.

I also used polar coordinates to solve the integral, which became

$$
\int_{1}^{2} \rho \left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{cos}\theta \; \mathrm{sin}\theta \;d\theta \right) d\rho = \frac{3}{4} = 0.75.
$$

My question is: why do the two methods give two different results with such a big difference?

Comment: You never adjusted the limits for $\rho$.  Your limits in the last remained the limits of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polar coordinate integral is correct. The cartesian integral is just wrong. The region $\Omega'$ in fact makes no sense: When $x>1$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is undefined. You have to split it up into two integrals, one with $0\le x\le 1$, and the other with $1\le x\le 2$. In the latter, the lower limit on $y$ is $0$. The moral of the story is: Draw pictures.

P.S. I have no idea what you did by hand or with Wolfram Alpha to get a real answer. Well, I have an idea ...

Comment: You're right.. my bad! I just didn't pay good attention in order to see that error. Just to be clear: when I try to get the simple domain, in fact I get two domains, one with 0 < x < 1 and one with 1 < x < 2? Also, I don't understand the p.s. .. I used a WolframAlpha widget for computing double integrals, and the result was 1.039. The limits were the ones I wrote in the question.

Comment: Interesting. It is plain wrong. Notice that your lower integration limit on $y$ becomes imaginary when $1<x<2$. ... Yes, you get two domains with the $y$ limits depending on which domain you are in :) I suggest you try doing your integral by hand — without guidance from Wolfram — and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I can clearly see that the answer on Wolfram is wrong, I think this is one of those situations where a paper and a pen are much better than a computer. Anyway, I will pay more attention in the future, I didn't check my calculations enough!

Comment: You're quite welcome :) Lesson learned! (Since you're new, let me remind you to accept the answer when you are satisfied. :))

Comment: I already tried to vote your answer but I need to have at least 15 reputation. Anyway, the vote has been recorded!

Comment: Interesting. By the way, I upvoted your question, because it is a quite interesting situation and you clearly had put effort into it :) Accepting the answer is different from upvoting it, though, so I'm not sure ;P